# Jumbotron and background images disappear when the window size changes from full screen to small

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

Have an issue with my homepage, the jumbotron/background images disappear when the window size changes from full screen to small screen, when it's resized the background/jumbotron images re-appear,how can the images be made responsive ?

Below is the styling:

```
    <style type = "text/css">
       .bd-placeholder-img {
         font-size: 1.125rem;
         text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
         -moz-user-select: none;
         -ms-user-select: none;
         user-select: none;
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
        font-size: 3.5rem;
        position:center;
        background-size:cover;
        background-attachment:fixed;
      }

      .jumbotron{
           margin-top:20px;
           background-image:url("{% static '9.jpg'%}" );
           background-repeat:no-repeat;
           background-size:cover;
           position:center;
           color:white;
       }

      body{
           background-image:url("{% static '8.jpg'  %}"); 
           background-repeat:no-repeat;
           background-size:cover;
           background-position:center center;
           background-attachment:fixed;
           overflow:visible;


   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are styling the classes inside this media query `@media (min-width: 768px)` this means that when a screen is smaller than that, the styles won't be applied. You need to take those styles out of the query.

```
<style type = "text/css">
       .bd-placeholder-img {
         font-size: 1.125rem;
         text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
         -moz-user-select: none;
         -ms-user-select: none;
         user-select: none;
    }

 
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
        font-size: 3.5rem;
        position:center;
        background-size:cover;
        background-attachment:fixed;
      }

      .jumbotron{
           margin-top:20px;
           background-image:url("{% static '9.jpg'%}" );
           background-repeat:no-repeat;
           background-size:cover;
           position:center;
           color:white;
       }

      body{
           background-image:url("{% static '8.jpg'  %}"); 
           background-repeat:no-repeat;
           background-size:cover;
           background-position:center center;
           background-attachment:fixed;
           overflow:visible;


   }
```